# Constructing a large balanced bipartition of $G(2n,1/2)$ with high probability

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Consider the random graph $G(2n,1/2)$. After picking each edge uniformly and independently with probability $1/2$ suppose that we have exactly $m$ edges in total (note: $m$ is not fixed!). Prove that there is a constant $a>0$ with the following property: with probability tending to $1$ as $n\to \infty$ we can partition the vertices of $G$ into classes $V_1$ and $V_2$ of sizes $|V_1| = |V_2| = n$ in a way so that the number of edges from $V_1$ to $V_2$ is at least $m/2 + an^{3/2}$.

There is a hint (though not enough for me to see the whole picture): Consider constructing $V_1$ and $V_2$ step-by-step, starting with $V_1=V_2=\emptyset$. In each step consider two new vertices $x$ and $y$, and either add $x$ to $V_1$ and $y$ to $V_2$ or vice-versa. Show that we can always ensure that at least half of the edges between $\{x,y\}$ and the earlier vertices join $V_1$ to $V_2$, and sometimes significantly more.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Well, what can you say about the distribution of $x$ and $y$'s neighbors in $V_1$ and $V_2$?

Comment: Well if currently $V_1$ and $V_2$ have $a_1$ and $a_2$ vertices, then the distribution on the number of edges from $x$ to $V_1$ is binomial with parameters $a_1$ and $1/2$. But this $a_1$ varies a lot as the suggested algorihtm in the hint goes on... So?

Comment: At each step, $a_1 = a_2 = $ total number of steps taken...

Comment: Good point, thank you! So you would bound from below the probability for the number of new added edges to be at least $a_1/2 + c\sqrt{a_1}$ (one can actually show that there is a constant $c$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X \geq a_1/2 + c\sqrt{a_1})\geq c$ for $X\sim$ Bin($a_1,1/2$) using Chernoff), then somehow when we sum these up, relying on $\sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{j} = \Theta(n^{3/2})$, we could get what we want? I am now not sure only about the ''summing up'' part, though.

Comment: Well, if you just need any constant bound, you could make your life easier by arguing that there's a $c$ such that in each of the last $\frac n2$ steps, the probability of getting an extra $c \sqrt n$ edges is at least $c$...

Comment: But then how does it follow that with high probability you will have in total $\gg n^{3/2}$ extra edges at the end? The probability that a fixed one from the last $n/2$ steps to not give $\gg n^{1/2}$ edges is $\leq c$ and so in total from all $n/2$ steps... how to bound the probability of ''bad things happen'' by something negligible?

Comment: You want another concentration bound: if each of $\frac n2$ steps has a $c$ probability of being helpful, you want to say that $\Omega(n)$ steps do actually turn out helpful.

Comment: I see, will try this, it should work! Thank you very much!